# How to render template without JavaScript in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I am using `iron:router` in meteor. In my case I wanna include Template in an Iframe.

template.html

```
<iframe src="{{pathFor 'MyTemplate'}}" width="100%"></iframe>
```

route.js

```
this.route('MyTemplate', {path: '/MyTemplate',layoutTemplate:'MyTemplate'});
```

When I render this temple in an iframe. It render with javascript and CSS. I need only css here. Is there anyway to restrict the JavaScript in specific route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its quite what you want but you can render HTML without meteor adding the javascript by doing this kind of thing:

```
Router.route('/MyTemplate', function () {
 this.response.end('<html><h1> hello world </h1></html>');
  }, {where: 'server'});
});
```

with that code in the server section.

Comment: I am new to meteor. I have n number of lines codes and the templates are dynamic. will it work?

Comment: You could modify the string in this.response.end( string ) to vary with your dynamic content. I don't personally know a way to get meteors templating system to output straight html/css as it's designed to send data over the wire to a javascript client. It may be possible but I don't know how.

Comment: There is some stuff on server side rendering here. https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr . Bit complicated though.